# Calling dynamic_sidebar in plugin gives error

Tags: plugin-development, sidebar

I am trying to call `dynamic_sidebar` from a plugin page. Whenever I do so,  it returns a white page! Any idea why?

What I am trying to do is to save the total sidebar output in a transient. I can get the sidebar output in a variable from the theme files, using this codes:

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar('name');
$sidebar= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

I can get the data in `$sidebar` and save it in a transient. But whenever I use this code from a plugin, the plugin admin page returns white screen. It happens whenever I call `dynamic_sidebar` in my plugin codes, doesn't matter what's before or after.

Does anyone know why? Or any solution please?

Comment: What debug info do you get?

Comment: @PieterGoosen My bad. I should have debug before asking a question. It was a syntax error. I was getting sidebar name from a function, which was not returning correctly. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure. A tip, always enable debug if you develop. Will help you a lot in future

Answer (score 0):

it's a little difficult to debug something when no errors are being displayed. i'd first check your php error logs, which normally appear in ....\logs\php_error.log or ....\logs\apache_erroe.log depending on your php.ini settings.

chances of getting an immediate answer to your question will be difficult unless you can provide the actual error that's popping up.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it by debugging. It was a syntax error.